# How to get dropdown list selected value in script using model in MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, nopcommerce

I'm trying to calculate the total of the selected quantity and price per piece. In some cases I have a list of allowed quantities, like 1000, 2000 etc in a dropdown list.

When I select the quantity from the dropdown it doesn't get the quantity as per the selected quantity.

View:

```
@if (Model.AllowedQuantities.Count > 0)
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EnteredQuantity, Model.AllowedQuantities, new { @class = "qty-dropdown", id = "productqty" })
}
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#productqty").change(function () {
            @{
                var qty = Model.EnteredQuantity;
                var qqt = "";
                var price = "";
                if (Model.AllowedQuantities.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var tierPrice in Model.TierPrices)
                    {
                        if (qty == tierPrice.Quantity)
                        {
                            price = tierPrice.Price;
                        }
                    }
                } else
                {
                    price = @Model.PriceValue.ToString("0.00", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                }

                }
            var prc = @price;
            var qt = @qty;
            var total = qt * prc;
            $("#productprice").text(total);
            console.log("Qty : " + qt + " Price : " + prc);
            console.log("Total : " + total);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `var qty = Model.EnteredQuantity;` is the original value. Use `var qty = Number($(this),val());` And `var price = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.PriceValue));` And do not try an mix razor code and javascript like that

Comment: @StephenMuecke First of all I am new to MVC so sorry for the coding, when using "var qty = Number($(this), val());" it shows an error "Non-invocable member 'Number' cannot be used like a method." and "The name 'val' does not exist in the current context. "

Comment: Sorry - typo -  its`$(this).val()` (dot, not comma)

Comment: Unexpected character '$'.

Comment: What?? - `$("#productqty").change(function () { var qty = Number($(this).val()); var price = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.PriceValue)); var total = qty  * price; $("#productprice").text(total); })`

Comment: No not like that. I have tier price for the products as per different quantity so when the quantity is changed it will check it with the tier quantity and set the price accordingly.

Comment: The you need to convert `TierPrices` to a javascipt array - `var tiers = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.TierPrices));` and find the corresponding value in the array. You cannot mix server side and client side code

Comment: Thank you for the help @StephenMuecke Can you give me an example related to javascript array and how to retrieve values from it ?. It will a big help from you.

Comment: You can just loop through it, for example using a `$.each(tiers, function(index, item) {` and compare the values as your doing now

Comment: Done that's working great. Thank you @StephenMuecke for all your help.